# Print script results to paragraph and console on button click

Tags: php

I would like this button to have a function which would print the results from the php file to a paragraph under it, and to the console. I have no experience in php, can someone please direct me what kind of function would I need to do this, do I assign onclick="" or something to the button..? Thank you for all help

```
    <button>Print to console</button>
    <h2>Printed results</h2>
    <p></p>

   <?php
    $data = array(

    'Lorem lorem ipsum'=>array(

            0=>array(
                'first_time' => '09:00',
                'second_time' => '10:20',
                'step_1' => 'lorem',
                'step_2' => 'lorem ipsum',
                'step_3' => 'lorem lorem',
            ),
            1=>array(
                'first_time' => '09:00',
                'second_time' => '10:20',
                'step_1' => 'lorem',
                'step_2' => 'lorem ipsum',
                'step_3' => 'lorem lorem',
            ),
        ),
    'Lorem ipsum dolor'=>array(

            0=>array(
                'first_time' => '09:00',
                'second_time' => '10:20',
                'step_1' => 'lorem',
                'step_2' => 'lorem ipsum',
                'step_3' => 'lorem lorem',
            ),
            1=>array(
                'first_time' => '09:00',
                'second_time' => '10:20',
                'step_1' => 'lorem',
                'step_2' => 'lorem ipsum',
                'step_3' => 'lorem lorem',
            ),
        ),
    'Lorem lorem lorem'=>array(

            0=>array(
                'first_time' => '09:00',
                'second_time' => '10:20',
                'step_1' => 'lorem',
                'step_2' => 'lorem ipsum',
                'step_3' => 'lorem lorem',
            ),
            1=>array(
                'first_time' => '09:00',
                'second_time' => '10:20',
                'step_1' => 'lorem',
                'step_2' => 'lorem ipsum',
                'step_3' => 'lorem lorem',
            ),
        )
    );              
    echo json_encode($data);

    ?>
```

Comment: Do you have any experience with Javascript?

Comment: Yes, but don't know how should I use it in this particular case.. I used javascript for some simple apps such as calculator, pomodoro clocks and similar, and jquery stuff for animations and similar

Comment: And do you know what AJAX is http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: yes I know the basics

Comment: Then just put them together. Write a Javascript function that performs an AJAX call to this script. When it gets the response it parses the JSON and displays the data.

Comment: Thanks I'll do my best!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `json_encode()` to convert the PHP array into a Javascript object literal. Then you can use it in a `click` listener.

```
<button id="but">Print to console</button>
<h2>Printed results</h2>
<p id="print"></p>

<?php
$data = array(

'Lorem lorem ipsum'=>array(

        0=>array(
            'first_time' => '09:00',
            'second_time' => '10:20',
            'step_1' => 'lorem',
            'step_2' => 'lorem ipsum',
            'step_3' => 'lorem lorem',
        ),
        1=>array(
            'first_time' => '09:00',
            'second_time' => '10:20',
            'step_1' => 'lorem',
            'step_2' => 'lorem ipsum',
            'step_3' => 'lorem lorem',
        ),
    ),
'Lorem ipsum dolor'=>array(

        0=>array(
            'first_time' => '09:00',
            'second_time' => '10:20',
            'step_1' => 'lorem',
            'step_2' => 'lorem ipsum',
            'step_3' => 'lorem lorem',
        ),
        1=>array(
            'first_time' => '09:00',
            'second_time' => '10:20',
            'step_1' => 'lorem',
            'step_2' => 'lorem ipsum',
            'step_3' => 'lorem lorem',
        ),
    ),
'Lorem lorem lorem'=>array(

        0=>array(
            'first_time' => '09:00',
            'second_time' => '10:20',
            'step_1' => 'lorem',
            'step_2' => 'lorem ipsum',
            'step_3' => 'lorem lorem',
        ),
        1=>array(
            'first_time' => '09:00',
            'second_time' => '10:20',
            'step_1' => 'lorem',
            'step_2' => 'lorem ipsum',
            'step_3' => 'lorem lorem',
        ),
    )
);              

?>
<script>
var data = <?php echo json_encode($data); ?>;
document.getElementById('but').addEventListener('click', function() {
    var html = '';
    for (var key in data) {
        html += '<h1>' + key + '</h1>';
        data[key].forEach(function(item) {
            html += '<p>first time: ' + item.first_time + '</p>';
            html += '<p>second time: ' + item.second_time + '</p>';
            html += '<p>step 1: ' + item.step_1 + '</p>';
            html += '<p>step 2: ' + item.step_2 + '</p>';
            html += '<p>step 3: ' + item.step_3 + '</p>';
        });
    }
    document.getElementById('print').innerHTML = html;
});
</script>
```

Comment: I get a syntax error SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'
 var data = <?php echo json_encode($data) ?>;   am I missing something..? Here's the link: https://jsfiddle.net/rq1yju1g/1/    @Barmar

Comment: jsfiddle doesn't execute PHP. This needs to be in a `.php` file on a server.

Comment: Yes I know but just wanted to show how it looks in my index.html on my local machine, I could not find something similar for php. So when I refresh the page it just shows all data from the php file plain unformatted in the browser, and gives the syntax error, and when I click the button it doesn't do anything :/  @Barmar

Comment: It should be `index.php`, unless you have your webserver configured to use PHP for `.html` files.

Comment: I don't have a configured server, and when I rename it to index.php my browser does not open it, it just offers me to open it with Sublime text. @Barmar

Comment: You need a server to run PHP, it doesn't run from local files.

Comment: I see..now I have configured xampp, and it prints objects to my console, but the data in the browser is just plain data, I guess I need to use JSON.parse now to format it? Will keep on searching, thank you!

Comment: No, you don't need to use `JSON.parse()`. `json_encode()` returns a string, but then we're echoing that into the Javascript source, so it becomes a Javascript object literal.

Comment: It's supposed to be plain data. You can use `data['Lorem lorem ipsum']` to access a specific part of it.

Comment: I'm figuring it out..if I give <p id="print"></p>  and try to display it with print.innerHTML = (data['Lorem ipsum ipsum']); it just displays [object Object], and what I am trying to do is access each object, wrap 'Lorem ipsum etc' in h1 and properties for example in <p>'s. For example print.innerHTML = (data['Lorem ipsum ipsum'].[0].second_time);, but this does not work properly

Comment: You can loop through the properties with `for (var key in data)`. Then you can access `data[key].first_time`, `data[key].second_time`, etc.

Comment: I apologize, maybe I wasn't clear enough, what I wish to achieve is to render this html to browser: <h1>Lorem lorem ipsum</h1>, then after that Array 0: <p>first_time: 09:00</p> etc., and like so for each array in each object. I have tried with for (var key in data){data[key].first_time} but can't figure out where to go from there

Comment: Your loop should concatenate all the HTML you want into a string, then it can assign it all to `print.innerHTML`.

Comment: I've updated my answer to show that. But this is really something you should be able to find in most javascript tutorials.

Comment: thank you so much. I have done some similar things, but I got confused with the inclusion of the php file and didn't realize that the same logic applies when combining with JS. learned a lot today, thank you once again